# how to upload image on amazon s3 using nodejs and make it public

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the following code to upload the image on amazon S3, but it is not public. What else parameter do I need to pass to make it public.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'}});
s3bucket.createBucket(function() {
var params = {Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
s3bucket.upload(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
  console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
} else {
  console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
}
});
});
```

Comment: this code is uploading text not image, second if you are new to aws-s3 then I would suggest to first create manually and allow permissions from aws dashboard for buckets and try uploading images.

Comment: Here is my simple solution aws-sdk with **IAM** user - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40188709/3057302

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make resource public when upload data at s3 bucket. I can able to download that link from any where.

Just try it:

```
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
  region: Constant.AWS_S3_REGION
 });
 console.log(filename);
 var params = {
  Key: filename,
  Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
  Bucket: Constant.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
  ACL:'public-read-write'
 };
s3bucket.upload(params, cb)
```

Cheers...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

For making data public in your bucket, convert following :

```
var params = {Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
```

To following:

```
var params = {Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!', ACL: 'public-read'};
```

For better understanding follow [This Good Tutorial](http://blog.katworksgames.com/2014/01/26/nodejs-deploying-files-to-aws-s3/)

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry My earlier code was

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');

var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

var fs = require('fs'),
    S3FS = require('s3fs'),
    s3fsImpl = new S3FS('****', {
    accessKeyId: '***',
    secretAccessKey: '**********'
});

// Create our bucket if it doesn't exist
s3fsImpl.create();

app.post('/api',multipartMiddleware, function (req, res) {

res.send(req.body, req.files);

var file = req.files.file;

var stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

return s3fsImpl.writeFile(file.originalFilename, stream).then(function () {

    fs.unlink(file.path, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
    res.status(200).end();
});
});
```