# AWS Lambda function write to S3

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a Node 4.3 Lambda function in AWS. I want to be able to write a text file to S3 and have read many tutorials about how to integrate with S3. However, all of them are about how to call Lambda functions after [writing to  S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html).

How can I create a text file in S3 from Lambda using node? Is this possible? Amazons documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Yes it is absolutely possible!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
function putObjectToS3(bucket, key, data){
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        var params = {
            Bucket : bucket,
            Key : key,
            Body : data
        }
        s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
        });
}
```

Make sure that you give your Lambda function the required write permissions to the target s3 bucket / key path by selecting or updating the IAM Role your lambda executes under.

**IAM Statement to add:**

```
{
    "Sid": "Stmt1468366974000",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name-goes-here/optional-path-before-allow/*"
    ]
}
```

**Further reading:**

- [AWS JavaScript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)
- The specific "[Put Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property)" details

Comment: If your lambda function is executed inside a VPC you will have to create an endpoint for it. Before finding this out the callback of s3.putObject was never called.

See this article about S3 VPC endpoint: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

See that one about accessing ressources from lambda: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: Could you specify how you would call this function? I'm guessing `bucket` comes from `process.env.BUCKET_NAME`, but what exactly is the `key` path, and `data`? What if you're writing the file in the Lambda first, and then putting it in a bucket?

Comment: As a late response to bildungsroman, `key` is anything that goes after your bucket name. For example, for `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/image.jpg`, the key is `path/to/image.jpg.`

Answer (score 10):

After long long time of silence-failing of 'Task timed out after X' without any good error message, i went back to the beginning, to Amazon default template example, and that worked!

> > Lambda > Functions > Create function > Use a blueprints > filter: s3.

Here is my tweaked version of amazon example:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

async function uploadFileOnS3(fileData, fileName){
    const params = {
        Bucket:  "The-bucket-name-you-want-to-save-the-file-to",
        Key: fileName,
        Body: JSON.stringify(fileData),
    };

    try {
        const response = await s3.upload(params).promise();
        console.log('Response: ', response);
        return response;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

IAM Statement for serverless.com - Write to S3 to specific bucket

```
service: YOURSERVICENAME

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1
  timeout: 60
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
       - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "**BUCKETARN**/*"
    - Effect: "Deny"
      Action:
        - s3:DeleteObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::**BUCKETARN**/*"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload file on s3 using

> aws-sdk

If you are using **IAM** user then you have to provide access key and secret key and make sure you have provided necessary permission to **IAM** user.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: "ACCESS_KEY",secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY'});
var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME'}});
function uploadFileOnS3(fileName, fileData){
    var params = {
      Key: fileName,
      Body: fileData,
    };
    s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, res) {               
        if(err)
            console.log("Error in uploading file on s3 due to "+ err)
        else    
            console.log("File successfully uploaded.")
    });
}
```

Here I temporarily hard-coded AWS access and secret key for testing purposes. For best practices refer to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html).

Comment: Nothing in the question requests specifically for access keys and secrets to be used for authentication. It is extremely bad practice to authenticate in this way and as such I don't feel recommending it as a solution is wise. Lambda functions should be provisioned with an IAM Role that is sufficient for the access the Lambda Function requires to perform it's function.

Comment: I know i just put the secret key and access key hard coded  but  this method only for small personal scripts or for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

One more option (export file as multipartFormFata):
React > Node.js (AWS Lambda) > S3 Bucket
https://medium.com/@mike_just_mike/aws-lambda-node-js-export-file-to-s3-4b35c400f484