# How to manage AWS Secret Keys for local development

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm writing a lambda function in Python 3.8. The function connects with a dynamodb using boto3:

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='foo', aws_access_key_id='foo', aws_secret_access_key='foo')
```

That is what I have while I am developing on my local machine and need to test the function. But, when I deploy this to lambda, I can just remove the credentials and my function will connect to the dynamodb [if I have the proper IAM roles and policies setup in place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162008/9376397). For example,  this code would work fine when deployed to lambda:

```
db = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='foo')
```

The question is, how can I manage this in terms of pushing code to lambda? I am using AWS SAM to deploy to AWS. Right now what I do is once I'm done developing my function, I remove the `aws_access_key_id='foo'` and `aws_secret_access_key='foo'` parts manually and then deploy the functions using SAM.

There must be a better way to do this? Could I embed these into my IDE instead? I'm using PyCharm. Would that be a better way? If not, what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **never** put credentials in the code like that.

When running the code locally, use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to store local credentials in a `~/.aws/config` file. The AWS SDKs will automatically look in that file to obtain credentials.

Answer (score 1):

In sam you can invoke your function locally using [sam local invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html) or [sam local start-lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-lambda.html).

Both of them take `--profile` parameter:

> The **AWS credentials profile** to use.

This will ensure that your local lambda environment executes with **correct credentials** without needing to hard code them in your code. Subsequently, you can test your code without modifications which would otherwise be needed when hard coding the key id and secret key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables.

Environment variables can be configured both [in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm), as well as in [AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html) and [AWS SAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-template-anatomy-globals.html).

As stated in the [Lambda best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html): "Use environment variables to pass operational parameters to your function. For example, if you are writing to an Amazon S3 bucket, instead of hard-coding the bucket name you are writing to, configure the bucket name as an environment variable."

You can also use an environment variable to specify which environment is being used, which can then be used to explicitly determine whether credentials are necessary.